# VB.NET How do I make calculation on some columns in datagridview from Form_Load event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm newbie in  vb.net and the forum , which I learned Much from it, I have a data importing from xml file to datagridview automaticly in the form load event , now I need a way to make calculation on some columns also in the form load event ,I dont want do it by cell changed or Cell End Edit event like this code I have:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    Try
        Dim order As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        If IsDBNull(order(0, e.RowIndex).Value) Then Exit Sub
        order("column name", e.RowIndex).Value = order("column name", e.RowIndex).Value * textboxvalue.Text
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

It work fine but I have to click each cell and tab out to see the result !!
Not good way for many cells to click !

What is the best way of doing this?
Thanks In advance

Comment: After it is loaded, how about a `For/Loop`? `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows`

Comment: Thank you OneFineday ..Can you please give me more details or code

Comment: My answer was not supposed to be used explicitly - you need to decide which cells to use. Plus it does nothing with the calculation. You need to decide what to do with it. Remember they are 0 based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example would add the first two columns. If you cannot guaranty them to be valid Integers then `Integer.TryParse` would be better. You can use other DataTypes like `Single` or `Double` as needed.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
  Dim total As Integer = Integer.Parse(row.Cells(0).Value) + Integer.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you again , No luck . there's cells are nulls ...shows error.

Comment: Then you have not filled the DGV yet.

Comment: No , this come after I but your code and made some modifed to cells numbers ...!!

Comment: I have shown you how to loop thru each row and how to do math with the values. it is your job to make sure the data is in there - I cannot do that from here.

Comment: Many Thanks my friend ,  I appreciate what you have done.I just keep trying to figure out a solution .

Comment: I would like to help you further, but you have not given me any info as to why it has empty values. Or what your doing with the calculations.

Comment: What a strange is there is no cell is empty in the datagrid or file loaded , I've make sure to remove any row or culomn is empty...when I uplaod the dataset by xml file it's ok ,when proceed this code error occur:An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll   ....!!!

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: Show me how you fill the grid. Just update the original post.

Comment: Show me a screen shot of the DGV with data in it.

Comment: Thank You For Your Help . I'm not allowed to rate your anser yet :( ..if I can I'll rate your answer towic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To OneFineDay I'd figured out the solution :

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        row.Cells("column name").Value = row.Cells("column name").Value * textboxValue.Text
    Next
```

Now I can calculate the desired column values by inserting its name ..
Thank You again OneFineDay for your appreciated help .